# Find unique (key: value) pair given N dictionaries in python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, dictionary

I would like to find an easy and/or fast way to find all *common* couple (pair: value) given N dictionaries in python. (*3.X would be best*)

**PROBLEM**

Given a set of 3 `dicts` (but it could be any `dict`, it is just for the example)

```
n1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
n2 = {'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
n3 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

The result for common (key: values) for `n1`, `n2` and `n3`
should be:

```
({'a': 1, 'c': 3})
```

And for `n2` and `n3` it should be

```
({'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': 4})
```

I first though about using a *brute force* algorithm that will check every pair (key: value) for every dict

Here is a implementation using a recursive algorithm

**SOLUTION A**

```
list_dict = [n1, n2, n3]

def finding_uniquness(ls):

    def recursion(ls, result):
        if not ls:
            return result
        result = {k: v  for k, v in result.items()  for k1, v1 in ls[0].items() if k == k1 and v == v1}
        return recursion(ls[1:], result)

    return recursion(ls[1:], ls[0])


finding_uniquness(list_dict)
# {'c': 3, 'a': 1}
```

But it is not easily understandable and the complexity is high
(I'm not sure how to calculate complexity; but since we compare all the elements on all `dict`, the complexity should be O(N²)?)

Then, I though about [`Sets`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). because it could naturally compare all the element

**SOLUTION B**

```
import functools

list_dict = [n1, n2, n3]
set_list = [set(n.items()) for n in list_dict]

functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, set_list)
 # {('a', 1), ('c', 3)}
```

It is so much better than the previous solution, unfortunately, when one of the `key` have a `list` as values it throws an error:

```
>>> n = {'a': [], 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> set(n.items())
```

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

My question is then double:

- is there any better algorithm than **SOLUTION A**?
- or is there a way to avoid the `TypeError` with **SOLUTION B**?

of course, any other remarks will be welcome.

Comment: You say "unique" several times but actually it seems you're looking for the _common_ key:value pair? In other words, the one that all dictionaries share.

Comment: which types can you have in your dictionaries? flat lists? lists of lists? because you could convert to `tuple` beforehand so the hash issue is gone.

Comment: @roganjosh yes, sorry, common is what I am looking for, I'd be pleased if you edit my questions. (or I will do it)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it is more of an abstract question, so eventually I could have _any_ types in my dictionnaries. Included nested `list`, `dict` etc...

Comment: A crude way of doing this would be to change Solution B to `set_list = [set(map(str, n.items())) for n in list_dict]` but then you'd probably need an OrderedDict.

Comment: @roganjosh that would make `6` and `"6"` equal for instance. Maybe safer with `repr`

Comment: **Pro tip**: In python3 `.items()`, `.values()` and `.keys()` already return set-like objects,hence there's no need to do `set(d.items())`!

Comment: @Bakuriu `values` isn't set-like and `items` isn't always set-like.

Comment: BTW good question. shows research, and generate some nice answers (that's a sign :))

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thx :)

Comment: @Bakuriu, I was thinking exactly the same but when I do `set(n) & set(n1)` (when `n`and `n1`) are `dict` it make the comparaison only over the `key` and not the values. Maybe I misanderstood what you were saying though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simpler and more efficient way:

```
>>> {k: v
     for k, v in list_dict[0].items()
     if all(k in d and d[k] == v
            for d in list_dict[1:])}
{'c': 3, 'a': 1}
```

Using an extra variable for `list_dict[1:]` might be beneficial, otherwise the short-circuiting of `all` somewhat goes to waste. Or if you don't need the list afterwards you could just pop the "master" dictionary:

```
>>> {k: v
     for k, v in list_dict.pop().items()
     if all(k in d and d[k] == v
            for d in list_dict)}
{'c': 3, 'a': 1}
```

Or using `get` with a default that cannot be in the dictionary as suggested by @Jean-FrançoisFabre:

```
>>> marker = object()
>>> {k: v
         for k, v in list_dict.pop().items()
         if all(d.get(k, marker) == v
                for d in list_dict)}
{'c': 3, 'a': 1}
```

Comment: that one I understand when I'm reading the code! (even at this late hour)

Comment: nitpick: `k in d and d[k] == v` could be `d.get(k,marker) == v` where `marker=object()`, to handle the case where keys could be `None`. That would probably be even faster.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ah, yeah, I thought about `get` but rejected it because of `None` and forgot about the trick you mention.

Comment: nice. edited a little bit more for clarity. Read this marker trick on SO a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre do you happen to remember the question that raised it? I understand how it works in this context but I'm interested in whether the question/answer elaborates on it more.

Comment: since I remembered `marker` as a name, it took me at least 3 seconds to find it :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41811832/pass-class-attribute-as-parameter-of-a-function-of-that-class-in-python/41811883#41811883. It didn't use a dictionary and `get` though, so I made that up myself (hoping to reuse it sometime in an answer). Basically, if you instanciate the object at this point, it cannot be in the dict (mutability helps :))

Answer (score 3):

If unhashable values are a problem you can always compute the intersection of the keys up-front by using `.keys()` and then compare only the values associated with the keys that all dictionaries have in common:

```
import operator as op
from functools import reduce

common_keys = reduce(op.and_, (d.keys() for d in my_dicts))
common_items = {}
for key in common_keys:
    value = my_dicts[0][key]
    if all(d[key] == value for d in my_dicts):
        common_items[key] = value
```

This should be pretty faster than solution a, slower than solution b, but works on all inputs.

Answer (score 1):

A batteries-included version.

To handle unhashable types, we use pickling; replace it with dill or json or any other predictable serialization to taste.

```
import collections
import itertools
import pickle  

def findCommonPairs(dicts):
    all_pairs = itertools.chain(*[d.items() for d in dicts])
    cnt = collections.Counter(map(pickle.dumps, all_pairs))
    return [pickle.loads(pickled_pair)
            for pickled_pair, count in cnt.items()
            if count == len(dicts)]


>>> findCommonPairs([n1, n2, n3])
[('a', 1), ('c', 3)]

>>> findCommonPairs([{'a': [1,2], 'b': [2,3]}, {'a': [1,2]}])
[('a', [1, 2])]
```

Note that serialization only goes so far. To properly compare dicts if dicts, for instance, these dicts must be turned into (key, value) pairs *and sorted* before serialization. Any structures that reference each other may have issues (or not). Replace pickling with a custom predictable serializer if you care about these issues.